# How to check some dependency for deb in preinst script when compat=9

Tags: software-installation, deb, packaging

I want to check some dependencies for the deb which compat equals to 9. If the dependency is not OK, just echo some warning but the deb can still be installed(It seems that Depends:xxx is not suitable for that). So I have tried the two ways:

1. add installer/preinst script The compile is OK but show issues when installing the deb:

   ```
   debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
   debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76, <> line 1.)
   debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
   (Reading database ... 77398 files and directories currently installed.)
   Preparing to unpack .../test_1.0.0-rc0.ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb ...
   dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new pre-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): No such file or directory.........................................................................................................................................]
   dpkg: error processing archive /mnt/package/tmp/test_1.0.0-rc0.ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
   subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
   Errors were encountered while processing:
   /mnt/package/tmp/test_1.0.0-rc0.ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
   ```
2. add some script in the installer/rules file, also not work

Could someone show me some samples how to reslolve it?

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking to make a late install of dependency without blocking the user from installing this package.

Actually, there are many samples in your current setup.

Example, search for some keywords like "answer" in the installed packages scripts: `preinst`, `postinst`, `prerm`, `postrm`. Like this:

```
grep -in answer /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.preinst
```